# Apk shared with android studio not working in some devices

Tags: android, android-studio

I have build apk from Android Studio it's working well on my device but on my
friend's device it installed the app and on clicking some button. it gives error that (appname has stopped working).How to fix this problem.

[image]

Comment: You should use [Firebase Crashlytics | Realtime Crash Reporting](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwijh6yKvLrfAhWBJCsKHRB2DsgYABAAGgJzZg&ohost=www.google.co.in&cid=CAESQOD26qCLotbTlyEoIvyBqZqkw_jJJulvkMMK76bUetP9xlZbsXdVFhyAvLOa8F1pvn5O6kFpMzzfHwPH3-519EY&sig=AOD64_0zOBPAltQIQyVbb26_-cDgC4H6zA&q=&ved=2ahUKEwi7xaaKvLrfAhXMsY8KHQ7QBRcQ0Qx6BAgMEAE&adurl=)

Answer (score 0):

Before release the APK , test it on Emulator for different versions on Android, plus you can implement Firebase Crashlytics to be aware of bugs that might happen later

Answer (score 0):

Remove app from your phone and try again to install.It will be crash on your device too. You should do null check for sharedPref.

Comment: I unistalled and reinstalled it but it didn't crash on my device. is shared prefrence really a problem.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error it is giving on my friends mobile

Answer (score 0):

- Perform clean project
- In Android Studio --> Build-->Build Apk, this will build the apk from scratch, sometimes intermediate apk's too might cause crashes
- If the problem still persists , please provide the details about your device and your friend's device( like manufacturer, android version)
- As above mentioned by other people it is always a good practise to integrate firebase crashlytics when you are delivering the apk to the outside world, as the code always works in developers device :)